# Problems installing Microsoft.Owin (for SignalR)

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

I'm trying to experiment with SignalR by adding it to an existing (but small) ASP.Net (.Net 4.6.1, VS 2017) web application. However, I'm having real problems getting the Nuget package installed; more specifically the `Microsoft.Owin` component (which appears to be a dependency).

I've followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr), but as soon as I try to install Owin - either explicitly, or indirectly by trying to install the main SignalR package, and regardless of whether it's via Package Manager or Package Manager Console - I get the error:

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin
>
> Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Owin.4.0.0' with respect to project
>   'SignalRProject', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
>
> Gathering dependency information took 43.64 ms Attempting to resolve
>   dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Owin.4.0.0' with
>   DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>
> Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
>   Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Owin.4.0.0'
>
> Resolved
>   actions to install package 'Microsoft.Owin.4.0.0'
>
> Retrieving package
>   'Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.
>
> Retrieving package 'Owin 1.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.
>
> Adding package 'Owin.1.0.0' to folder 'c:\code\SignalRProject\packages'
>
> **Install failed. Rolling back...**
>
> Package 'Owin.1.0.0' does not exist in project
>   'SignalRProject'
>
> Removing package 'Owin.1.0.0' from folder
>   'c:\code\SignalRProject\packages'
>
> Install-Package : TF400024: The
>   change on c:\code\SignalRProject\packages\Owin.1.0\Owin.1.0.nupkg
>   cannot be undone because a file already exists at
>   c:\code\SignalRProject\packages\Owin.1.0\Owin.1.0.nupkg. The file
>   must be deleted from  disk for the undo to succeed.

I've tried the `Owin.1.0.nupkg` file, and the parent directory itself, but after restarting VS I continue to get the error. I've tried upgrading to .Net 4.7.1, but to no effect. How can I find out what's causing the Owin install error?

Comment: That guide may be out of date a little with respect to Owin. 

Have you tried just installing the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR v2.2.2 package? I just did a test on a brand new project and it installed Owin v1.0.0 and Microsoft.Owin v4.0.0 without issue along with all other dependencies.

Comment: @FrankM: Yes, I started out by trying to install the main SignalR package, but it got stuck at the Owin part - hence me trying to install it separately. I've managed to get it installed by using the 3rd party `Paket` utility, but I'd still be keen to know what's breaking Nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work around my issue, and get Owin (and SignalR) installed by using the 3rd-party [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) Nuget alternative.

```
>paket.exe add Microsoft.Owin --project SignalRProject
Paket version 5.148.0
Dependencies files saved to c:\code\SignalRProject\paket.dependencies
Adding package Microsoft.Owin to c:\code\SignalRProject\paket.references into group Main
References file saved to c:\code\SignalRProject\paket.references
 - Creating model and downloading packages.
 - paket.references -> SignalRProject.csproj
Performance:
 - Disk IO: 63 milliseconds
 - Runtime: 6 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could donwload a running microsoft example and then compare with yours https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-c366b2f3

Answer (score 0):

> Install-Package : TF400024: The change on
>   c:\code\SignalRProject\packages\Owin.1.0\Owin.1.0.nupkg cannot be
>   undone because a file already exists at
>   c:\code\SignalRProject\packages\Owin.1.0\Owin.1.0.nupkg. The file must
>   be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.

This error is caused by TFVC source control. You should first check-in your changes and then install nuget packages

Comment: You're right, I'm using TFVC, but I'm afraid checking in the project (and solution) didn't make any difference :(